# iOS 9.3 Offers Update to iOS 9.3

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Last week I upgraded to iOS 9.3 on my iPhone 5S and my 2nd Gen iPad Mini. Last night both started offering me an upgrade to iOS 9.3 *again*, even going so far as to download the 1.5GB update file.

Is anyone else seeing this behavior? Any idea how to resolve the issue short of installing the update? I would venture a guess that it's a server-side issue at Apple that I can't do too much about, but I'm wondering if anyone else has any ideas.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Update (March 31, 2016)**: Apple has released iOS 9.3.1 (`13E238`***) to fix more issues. If you update to that, this issue will be resolved.

---

**Original Answer**

There were [some issues](http://9to5mac.com/2016/03/28/apple-re-releases-ios-9-3-for-older-iphones-and-ipads-affected-by-activation-lock-issue/) in the original release of iOS 9.3 (`13E233`*) for older devices. A newer build (`13E237`**) was released on March 28, 2016.

You can check your installed build in `Settings > General > About > Version`. If your installed build is `13E233`*, that may be the reason for your indication. Whether you choose to update is your choice. If you choose to not, then you may have to just deal with the notifications (until the next real update).

***Note:*** Build numbers vary per device.
`13E233`*: all devices except iPhone 6s/6s Plus and iPad Pro (9.7 inch).
`13E234`*: iPhone 6s, iPhons 6s Plus, iPad Pro (9.7 inch).
`13E236`**: iPad 2 (3G, GSM).
`13E237`**: all iPads except iPad Air 2, iPad Pro (9.7 and 12.9), iPad mini 3 and iPad mini 4. all iPhones except iPhone 6/6 Plus, iPhone 6s/6s Plus, and iPhone SE. iPod touch (5th Generation).
`13E238`***: all devices currently supported by Apple.

Comment: I have 13E234 installed on my iPhone 6s, why's that?

Comment: You'd think that would make it iOS 9.4, or 9.3.1 or something. Maybe it wasn't good for aesthetics though.

Comment: I'll add some extra information.